Использован некорректный синтаксис почтового адреса. contact-form 7 wordpress
такая ситуация сайт имеет русский домен и он почему-то не хочет принимать его в контактной форме.
Кто-то сталкивался с подобным? Знает как исправить в настройках формы от кого не могу вписать ни сайт ни доменную почту потому что она на русском языке При попытке вставить другое название почты говоирт что она не связана с этим доменом.

Cyrillic domain Invalid mailbox syntax is used
